# Angular 1.5 - UI-Router, Resolve Object returning undefined values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am unable to get resolved data (via resolve object) from ui router pre-loaded into a component controller. the properties are showing up in the component's `this` object, but all properties are undefined. Why is this happening? I have been stuck on this for a while now...

here is the component:

```
  .component('wLoans', {
    template: require('./loans.html'),
    controller: LoansController,
    bindings: {
      settings: '<',
      labels: '<'
    }
  });
```

this.settings and this.labels appear, but they are undefined. when I console.log inside resolve.settings below, I can see the promise itself. in the promise below, `value` contains the return data I want:[image]

below is the state I am working on with UI router:

```
{
      name: 'loans',
      parent: 'app',
      url: '/loans',
      data: {
        authRequired: true
      },
      views: {
        content: {
          template: '<w-loans></w-loans>'
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        labels(LabelService) {
          'ngInject';
          return LabelService.fetch();
        },
        settings(SettingsService) {
          'ngInject';
          console.log(SettingsService.fetch());
          return SettingsService.fetch()
        },
        module($q, $ocLazyLoad, LabelService) {
          'ngInject';
          return $q((resolve) => {
            require.ensure([], (require) => {
              let mod = require('pages/loans');
              $ocLazyLoad.load({ name: mod.name });
              resolve(mod.name, LabelService.fetch());
            }, 'loans');
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

here is the fetch function from the service that's being called in the route:

```
function fetch() {
        // return $http.get(require('!!file!mocks/settings.json'), {
    return $http.get(`${DEV_API_URL}/settings`, {
      cache: settingsCache,
      transformResponse: [
        ...$http.defaults.transformResponse,
        transformResponse
      ]
    })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        angular.extend(model, data);
        settingsCache.put('store', model);
        return model;
      });
  }
```

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE: using ui router 1.0.0-beta.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are not using the 1.0.0 (currently beta) version of the ui-router there is no way to directly use the components. For the beta version, please see this discussion: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2627. There is also a tutorial on how to use routing to components with resolves: https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/hellogalaxy

What you are doing here is creating a state named `loans` with an implicit controller and scope which will have the resolved data assigned. In the template you then instantiate your component without passing any of the attributes required.

So if you want to use your component with the 0.2.x ui-router, you need to add some dummy controller which gets the resolved properties injected and then pass the values of the dummy controller into the component via the template like

```
<w-loans settings="settings" .../>
```

Depending on how new your version of the ui-router is (0.3.x?), you can probably use the newly introduced `$resolve` property to avoid creating a dummy controller like this:

```
<w-loans settings="$resolve.settings" ...></w-loans>
```

Details here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2793#issuecomment-223764105

Comment: I'm using the beta version. let me update my question with that info

Comment: Great. Then it's pretty straightforward to use your components directly. There is even a tutorial covering the `resolve` handling with components in the beta docs page: https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/hellogalaxy

Comment: hey Andreas, any thoughts on this question of mine also related to UI router? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277446/unable-to-invoke-uicanexit-angular-ui-router-1-0-0-beta

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Angular 1.6 and it looks like a different  behavior of this version. My view is rendered after the promise is resolved, but the controller is called before, I think. It works for me using $onInit like the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-bcd0d4) suggests:

```
.component('myComponent', {
  bindings: {value: '<'},
  controller: function() {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      // do somthing with this.value
    };
  }
})
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15545