# unable to invoke uiCanExit - angular ui router 1.0.0 beta

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following routes file in `components/app/app-routes.js`:

```
export default
function AppRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $transitionsProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  // reference: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#lazy-resolves
  const defaultResolvePolicy = {
    when: 'EAGER'
  };

  const STATES = [{
    name: 'logout',
    url: '/logout?applicationName&desktopName&sn',
  }, {
    name: 'base',
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
  }, {
    name: 'app',
    parent: 'base',
    abstract: true,
    component: 'wireApp',
    data: {
      authRequired: true
    },
    resolvePolicy: defaultResolvePolicy,
    resolve: {
      labels(LabelService) {
        'ngInject';
        return LabelService.fetch();
      },
      settings(SettingsService) {
        'ngInject';
        return SettingsService.fetch();
      },
    }
  }, {
    name: '404',
    url: '/404',
    parent: 'base',
    template: '<w-404></w-404>',
    resolvePolicy: defaultResolvePolicy,
    resolve: {
      module($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
        'ngInject';

        return $q((resolve) => {
          require.ensure([], (require) => {
            let mod = require('pages/404');
            $ocLazyLoad.load({
              name: mod.name
            });
            resolve(mod.name);
          }, '404');
        });
      },
    }
  }, {
    name: 'dashboard',
    parent: 'app',
    url: '/dashboard',
    data: {
      authRequired: true
    },
    views: {
      'content@app': {
        template: '<w-dashboard priority-tasks="$resolve.priorityTasks"></w-dashboard>'
      },
    },
    resolvePolicy: {
      module: defaultResolvePolicy,
      priorityTasks: {
        when: 'LAZY'
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      priorityTasks($http, $q, CacheFactory, CustomerService, RuntimeConfig, PermissionService) {
        'ngInject';

        if (!CacheFactory.get('priorityTasks')) {
          CacheFactory.createCache('priorityTasks', {
            storageMode: 'sessionStorage',
            storagePrefix: 'w'
          });
        }

        const priorityTasksCache = CacheFactory.get('priorityTasks');

        if (PermissionService.check('PRIORITY_TASKS', 'view')) {
          return $http.get(`${RuntimeConfig.DEV_API_URL}/customer/${CustomerService.model.currentCustomer.id}/priority-tasks`, {
            cache: priorityTasksCache
          }).then(({
            data
          }) => data, () => $q.resolve([]));
        }
        return [];
      },
      module($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
        'ngInject';

        return $q((resolve) => {
          require.ensure([], (require) => {
            let mod = require('pages/dashboard');
            $ocLazyLoad.load({
              name: mod.name
            });
            resolve(mod.name);
          }, 'dashboard');
        });
      }
    }
  }, {
    name: 'loans',
    parent: 'app',
    url: '/loans',
    data: {
      authRequired: true
    },
    views: {
      'content@app': {
        template: '<w-loans></w-loans>',
      },
    },
    resolvePolicy: defaultResolvePolicy,
    resolve: {
      security($q, $state) {
        'ngInject';
        //irl get this from a service.
        console.log($transitionsProvider, "TRANSISIONS PROVIDER FROM ROUTE");
        // let permissions = false;
        // if (!permissions) {
        //   return $q.reject("No permissions");
        // }
      },
      module($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
        'ngInject';
        return $q((resolve) => {
          require.ensure([], (require) => {
            let mod = require('pages/loans');
            $ocLazyLoad.load({
              name: mod.name
            });
            resolve(mod.name);
          }, 'loans');
        });
      }
    }
  }];

  $urlRouterProvider
    .when('', '/dashboard')
    .when('/', '/dashboard')
    .when('/login', '/dashboard')
    .otherwise('/404');

  //this will redirect all rejected promises in routes to a 404. 
  $transitionsProvider.onError({
    to: '*',
    from: '*'
  }, (transition) => {
    let $state = transition.router.stateService;
    $state.go('404');
  });

  STATES.forEach((state) => {
    $stateProvider.state(state);
  });


}
```

in my loans controller (associated state above, 'loans'), however, I am unable to access the new `uiCanExit` callback.:

```
   .component('wLoans', {
    template: require('./loans.html'),
    controller: LoansController,
    bindings: {
      settings: '<',
      labels: '<'
    }
  });



 function LoansController($window, $timeout, $http, $compile, $log, $filter, LoansService, ConfigService, ngDialog, SettingsService, CustomerService, ColumnRenderService, $transitions) {
  'ngInject';

  this.uiCanExit = function () {
        console.log("WHY AM I NOT GETTING HERE");
      }
}
```

nothing appears in the console when I switch between states, and I'm trying to figure out what to do to get the uiCanExit lifecycle hook to be run when I switch in between states (particularly `dashboard` and `loans`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but could the problem be caused by not referencing the component directly? Probably this only works when you reference your `loans` component via the `component` key instead of placing them in a `template` which renders the component. I assume that in your case the router tries to find the callback in the (not declared and thus dummy) controller instead of using the component's controller.

Please have a look at the docs: https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1controller.html#uicanexit

You can validate this assumption by putting a `controller` implementation with the `uiCanExit()` method in your `loans` state.

Comment: Interesting will take a look soon. My temporary workaround was using transitions.onBefore where I was trying to get uiCanExit